# roundslider js not rendering properly html2canvas

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html2canvas, webpage-screenshot

This is my webpage:
[image]

I use the latest version of html2canvas 1.0.0-rc.5
After html2canvas this is the result[image]

Here is my code:

```
html2canvas($(".viewReport")[0], {
    allowTaint: true, scale: 1}).then(function (canvas) {



        canvas.getContext('2d');
        imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);

        window.open().document.write('<img src="' + imgData + '" />');
    });
```

Comment: are you using https://roundsliderui.com/ ?

Comment: yes i use roundsliderui.com with some css modifications.

Comment: It seems the issue from the html2canvas library only, you can raise a issue report in their repo for a better help: https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues